# Making two columns have a unique key, but only when both are matched?

Tags: php, mysql

**I have the following table structure:**

```
OFFER_ID -|- COUNTRY -|- URL
   1     -|-    GB   -|- http://www.example.com/1
   1     -|-    US   -|- http://www.example.com/2
   1     -|-    FR   -|- http://www.example.com/3
```

What I want is to update the `URL` when **BOTH** the `OFFER_ID` and `GB` are already existent within the table.

**For example, if the query was:**

`INSERT INTO table_name (offer_id, country, url) VALUES ('1','DE', 'http://www.example.com/3')`

**OR**

`INSERT INTO table_name (offer_id, country, url) VALUES ('2','FR', 'http://www.example.com/4')`

A new row would be inserted as although the values for `OFFER_ID` (in ex. 2) and `COUNTRY` (in ex. 1) are new, the values for `COUNTRY` (in ex. 2) and `OFFER_ID` (in ex. 1) aren't.

**However, with a query like this:**

`INSERT INTO table_name (offer_id, country, url) VALUES ('1','FR', 'http://www.example.com/7')`

The `URL` column would be updated.

I know using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=VALUES(url)` would be the way forward, but how would I be able to structure it so that ONLY when both `OFFER_ID` and `COUNTRY` are not unique, the `URL` column is updated as oppose to a new row being inserted?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make both a part of the primary key

```
PRIMARY KEY (`offer_id`, `country`)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique index on (OFFER_ID, COUNTRY), and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will work:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD UNIQUE INDEX offer_id_country (OFFER_ID, COUNTRY);
```

Or a primary key if you don't have one already:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD PRIMARY KEY (OFFER_ID, COUNTRY);
```

Comment: Thanks :). Why the `offer_id_country` concatenated string, what's that for?

Comment: @Pixelatron: it's the name of the index. You can specify any name you like, while `offer_id_country` reflects that both `offer_id` and `country` are included in this particular one.

Comment: @zerkms - I guess I got mixed up with `UNIQUE KEY` and `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Comment: @Pixelatron: `UNIQUE KEY`? The `key` term in mysql means the same as `index`. They are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the primary key for that table to `(OFFER_ID,COUNTRY)`. (Or set a `UNIQUE` constraints on that pair of columns.)

Comment: It does sound like it would be a very proper use of a primary key though.

Comment: yep, but my thought was about pointing that it can be just a composite unique key either. Btw, if OP uses innodb as a storage engine, then using something that doesn't grow monotonously as a PK is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mysql's `REPLACE` function. After creating a unique key on (OFFER_ID, COUNTRY).

```
REPLACE INTO table_name (offer_id, country, url) VALUES ('1','FR', 'http://www.example.com/7')
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` work the same, or does this essentially do the same thing, but with less overhead?

Comment: I guess it would, but with REPLACE, no need to alter the table's structure